# Closing old window when opening a new one in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Ok, I have two windows, `A` and `B`.  When I click a button on `Window A`, I want it to close and take the user to `Window B`.  `makeKeyAndOrderFront` does a great job of activating `Window B`, but how do you get it to then close `Window A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send window A a [`close`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close) or [`performClose:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performClose:) message (depending on whether you want to emulate the user closing the window, which is the latter, or simply close it immediately and unconditionally).

Note that closing the window may release it; see [the `releasedWhenClosed` property](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setReleasedWhenClosed:), which has a checkbox in IB and may already be turned on there. You may want to [order the window out](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/orderOut:) (as compared to ordering in, such as by ordering front) instead.